# How to integrate a private Google Calendar?

Tags: datetime, emails, files

My client is a counseling center that would like to use Google Calendar to record and manage confidential information when clients schedule appointments online.  The catch is that they want it to be a private Google Calendar.

Is this possible?

Can a private Google Calendar be embedded with a drupal site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Google Calendar API (GCal)](http://drupal.org/project/gcal)

> This module uses google api php client refer
> http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to interact with
> google and manage calendars
>
> **Requirements**
>
> [GAuth](http://drupal.org/project/gauth) - Required for authenticating with google.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check this out.  Have you used this before?